# How to style blockquotes in a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kind of new to Javascript and have been doing small projects to get myself acquainted with the language. I've done things like draggable boxes, a calculator, etc., and now I'm working on a small WYSIWYG editor for practice and possibly a future site.

In this project I'm using an `iframe` as the text box using this snippet of code:

```
<!-- images as buttons -->
<iframe id='reply'></iframe>

<script>
var doc;

doc = document.getElementById('reply');
doc = doc.contentDocument || document.frames.reply.document;
doc.designMode = 'on';
</script>
```

to access the document of the iframe. After accessing the document I use various calls to `doc.execCommand('someCommand', false, null);` to create the editing interface. I've gotten several buttons to work (bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, sub and superscript, etc.) but I'm having trouble with block quotes. This is for a theoretical message board and the editor needs to be able to make long quotations recognizable, much like how the blockquote button on Stack Overflow operates.

To make this work, so far I've used `doc.execCommand('formatblock', false, '<blockquote>');`. This method will indent the text properly, but my CSS doesn't effect it. I assume this is because the CSS on that document doesn't apply inside the iframe . . . but I don't know how to style the stuff inside of it. Is there a way to insert a stylesheet inside the iframe? Am I going about this all wrong? Should I perhaps try a textarea over an iframe? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can link to stylesheets within an iframe, or at least use `style` tags in the `head`. An iframe is just an external HTML page, after all.

Comment: @Danae, when you say use style sheets in the head, are you saying to do something like `#reply blockquote { /* style here */ }`? Because I've tried that and it didn't work . . . I'll try adding a stylesheet to the iframe though. I just think that's more work than it needs to be . . .

Comment: How about inline styles? It's not recommended but if you can stick it in the `<blockquote>` tag when you render it, it gives it priority over any external stylesheets.

Comment: @Danae You mean using `doc.execCommand('formatblock', false, '<blockquote style="background-color: #eeeeee;">');`? Hmm, I tried it and it wouldn't even indent properly.

Comment: I'm afraid I've reached my limitations with help...All I can advise is to use Firebug or Chrome to inspect what is going on in the iframe when you try to apply blockquotes. It could use some crazy different tag, or a class.

Comment: @Danae No worries! You've helped, believe me. Thanks for trying! :)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off outputting the results to a div as it forms part of the dom for the page you're viewing. Iframes are for loading independant urls and pages therefore you'd need to style the page within the iframe or link to the same stylesheet as the page containing the iframe.

How about a div like this you can set the oveflow property in the css to overflow: scroll; and get a similar effect to the iframe whilst keeping all your elements in the same page?

```
<div id='reply'></div>
```

Css for the div

```
#reply {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  /* additional properties */
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: I think you've given me some good ideas, and thank you for that. But I don't think this will quite work because when I use `execCommand`, I can't give the element an id or a class, so I think I might have to do something like `iframe div { /* whatever */ }` or, like you said, just make an independent style sheet for that `iframe`. Thanks!